# GooglePay and ApplePay Option is not getting display in BrainTree Drop-In UI for Flutter

Tags: flutter, braintree, google-pay, flutter-ios, flutter-android

I am using flutter_braintree plugin version 1.2.1. Also given applePay and googlePay Request in Drop-In Request. Still both option are not getting display in Drop-In UI(only card and paypal is getting display) in flutter IOS.

final request = BraintreeDropInRequest(
clientToken: 'sandbox_f252zhq7_hh4cpc39zq4rgjcg',
collectDeviceData: true,
cardEnabled: true,

```
            googlePaymentRequest: BraintreeGooglePaymentRequest(
              totalPrice: '4.20',
              currencyCode: 'USD',
              billingAddressRequired: true,
            ),

            paypalRequest: BraintreePayPalRequest(
              amount: '4.20',
              displayName: 'Example company',
            ),
            applePayRequest: BraintreeApplePayRequest(
                displayName: 'NAME',
                amount: 100.4,
                currencyCode: format.currencyName,
                appleMerchantID: 'merchant_ID',
                countryCode: '+91')
          );

          BraintreeDropInResult result =
              await BraintreeDropIn.start(request);
          if (result != null) {
            print('Nonce: ${result.paymentMethodNonce.nonce}');
            final PaymentMethods paymentMethods = Provider.of(context);
            var future = await paymentMethods.createPaymentMethod(
                parent, '567777', '${result.paymentMethodNonce.nonce}');
             future.then((_) {
              showSuccess(context, 'Saved!');
            });

            future.catchError((e) {
              GrpcError err = e;
              showError(context, err.message);
            });
          } else {
            print('Selection was canceled.');
          }
```

Comment: Check this ==> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52741477/braintree-dropin-apple-pay-doesnt-appears-apple-pay-item

Comment: @AwaisRehman i have checked that ..but still issue is not resolved...and not getting ApplePay Button in Drop-In UI.